# How does a black colored environment make coloured objects appear more vivid?

Tags: optics, visible-light

I am doing some research regarding stains on a white fabric. I need to take a picture of a stained piece of fabric, analyze the colors of the stains on the fabric using a computer program and use that information for further analysis. As such, I have made a a special cardboard box for taking pictures. The inside is painted completely black and there is a cut-out on the top with room for one light source and one camera.

I have noticed that the pictures really do show a more clear picture of the stains, in that the colors appear more vivid and as such the stain is easier to visually separate from the fabric itself.

I'm not sure how this can be explained in physical terms and the work I'm doing is more chemistry related so, from the theoretical side, it was more of a hunch that the black box would have helped. So I would like to ask: how do I explain my usage of the black colored box in optical terms, considering the fact that the black box does help in the picture analysis?

Comment: How do you take the pictures? If it's a digital camera, it likely does lots of image processing that alters the appearance of colors — including hue (white balancing) and saturation ("enhancement"). To compare the colors in a more controlled environment you should shoot RAW and manually develop the photos with the identical settings.

Comment: Thank you for that observation, I take pictures with a phone camera that has specific settings set to constants. The settings are:
• Exposure time: 1/40 sec.
• Aperture value: 2.27 EV (f/2.2)
• ISO Speed rating: 125
• Focal length: 3.8 mm.

Comment: Unfortunately these settings don't fix the other aspects of processing. At the very least you should fix white balance temperature and tint, but there may also be some non-configurable parameters affecting the colors. So if your phone is able to save RAW files, try using this option.

Comment: It can, thanks for the tip!

Comment: As for Ruslan comments, digital photos reflect the skill and taste of the camera developer as much as that of the photographer. But in this case there might also be a lot of neuro/psychological aspects involved.

Answer (score 0):

colored object  are processed by the brain in such a way that the perceived colors depend on context (that is, what other colors are around). I do not want to enter into details about why, but it is related to the brain trying to guess the most likely color given a specific stimuli, in most cases it attempts to calculate color constancy after the colors are affected by shadows, other surrounding colors, or  other situations. There are multiple [color illusions](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/54448/5-color-illusions-and-why-they-work), and they are related on how the brain process color, not on the actual  physical wavelengths of the colors in the image.